# Subfunction returning choropleth map

Tags: python, plotly, visualization, choropleth

I have two functions, one part of another:
One returns values lat, lon, df, zoom, geojson based on input
This function works fine
Another function is supposed to return a choropleth map based on inputs that are outputs for the first function, i .e. inputs here are lat,lon,df,zoom,geojson

Let's suppose that these are outputs for the first function:

```
lat=39.90341108652551
lon=-76.12312247933444
zoom=10
df=df2
geojson=geo_lower
```

geo_lower is a json file from:

```
geo_lower='https://www.redistricting.state.pa.us/Resources/GISData/Districts/Legislative/House/2021-Final/JSON/2022%20LRC-House-Final.json'
with urlopen(geo_lower) as response:
    geo_lower = json.load(response)
```

df2 looks like one-row dataframe:

| District | Total Popultation | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 234,678 | ... |

The second function looks like this:

```
fig=px.choropleth_mapbox(df,
                         geojson=geojson,
                         locations='District',
                         mapbox_style="carto-positron",
                         zoom=zoom,
                         center={'lat':lat, 'lon':lon},
                         opacity=0.3)
```

The result is:
[image]

However, if i input values manually, the function returns intended outcome:

```
fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(df2, 
                           geojson=geo_lower,
                           locations='District',
                           mapbox_style="carto-positron",
                           zoom=10,
                           center={'lat':39.90341108652551,'lon':-76.12312247933444},
                           opacity=0.3
                           )
fig.show()
```

[image]

I believe the problem is with the second function's center, because when i print(fig), its center is not the same as the input center:
[image]

How can I solve the issue?

Comment: The first map also has the area filled in purple if you scroll to the right.

Comment: yes, but the center of the map is not what i want it to be. I want the center of the map to be the center of the purple polygon, so that user dont have to scroll to the right.

Comment: Is the original center point off? If you manually find the center, you will get the following. `lat=39.965694;lon=-75.209042`